# Custom search results page not showing excerpt

Tags: search, excerpt

I have a custom content-searchresults.php page. However for some reason its not showing the excerpt, but other amends I make this on this are pulled through so it is using this template.

Below is my code.

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() && !is_single() ) : ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));   ?>
            </a>


        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <header class="entry-header ">
                <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && CrippsTheme_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'CrippsTheme' ) ); ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php
                    endif;

                    if ( is_single() ) :
                        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
                    else :
                        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
                    endif;
                ?>

            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        </div>


    <div class="entry-summary clearfix">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <div class="clearfix">
    <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
        Read more
    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using this as a page template, and running your own query? Or are you simply using the "native" search archive, `?s=whatever`?

Comment: im using the native search archive. Ive realised what the problem is, its because I use an advanced custom field as my main copy. Is it possible to get the excerpt of an acf?

Comment: You can use the [`wp_trim_words()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) function with `get_field( 'my_content_field' )`.